# Retrofit v2.0.0-beta2 how to upload file using RequestBody

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I am trying to post images to the server. Here are my php variable names on the server side provided to me by scriptor:

```
$value1 = $_POST["value1"]; // string value
$value2 = $_POST["value2"]; // string value

$img_1 = $_FILES["fileToUpload1"]["name"]; // image file
$img_2 = $_FILES["fileToUpload2"]["name"]; // image file
```

and here is my code for posting the values -

```
RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), path.toString());
RequestBody fileBody1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), path.toString());

Call<uploadResponseModel> call = adapter.uploadValues("test1","test2",fileBody1,fileBody);

call.enqueue(new Callback<uploadResponseModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<uploadResponseModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
         Log.i("TAG", "retro onResponse :" + response.body().getResponse().getStatus());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        Log.i("TAG", "retro onFailure :" + t.getCause());
    }
});
```

adapter class:

```
public interface RetrofitAdapter {
 @Multipart
 @POST("/TestApp/img_upload.php")
 Call<uploadResponseModel> uploadValues(@Part("value1")String  value1,@Part("value2")String  value2,@Part("fileToUpload1") RequestBody file1,@Part("fileToUpload2") RequestBody file2);
}
```

Both string values are getting posted on the server, but not the images. Please correct me if i am wrong anywhere in posting image files. I am new to retrofit.

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you? Can you post your solution here?

Comment: @Rakesh : No. none of them worked for me. finally ended using retrofit 1.9 which works smoothly in uploading images

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your question, the variable that your server expects as the two images(files) are `fileToUpload1` and `fileToUpload2`. The reason why the images are'nt getting uploaded are because of the syntax you have specified in your `RetrofitAdapter`.

You will have to change your `RetrofitAdapter` to:

```
public interface RetrofitAdapter {
 @Multipart
 @POST("/TestApp/img_upload.php")
 Call<uploadResponseModel> uploadValues(@Part("value1")String  value1,@Part("value2")String  value2,@Part("fileToUpload1\"; filename=\"image\" ") RequestBody file1,@Part("fileToUpload2\"; filename=\"image\" ") RequestBody file2);
}
```

> @Part("fileToUpload1\"; filename=\"image\" ") RequestBody file1

The server expects the file with the variable name `fileToUpload1` and `fileToUpload2` which has to be posted along with a file name in the above format. You could refer the solution here as well [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34965841/5846547)

Do this and you are good to go :)

Comment: yeah! this solved my problem. my file name i was posting was wrong. than x for correcting my syntax !!

Answer (score 2):

This is my service method for multipart file upload:

```
@Multipart
@POST("http://....")
Call<UploadResponse> uploadPicture(@PartMap Map<String,RequestBody>  pic1, @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> pic2);
```

And how to call it:

```
  public void uploadPicture(File pic1, File pic2) {
      Map<String, RequestBody> pic1Map = new HashMap<>();
      Map<String, RequestBody> pic2Map = new HashMap<>();
      RequestBody rb1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), pic1);
      RequestBody rb2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), pic2);
      pic1Map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + pic1.getName(), rb1);
      pic2Map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + pic2.getName(), rb2);

      Call<UploadResponse> call = apiClient.getAPIService().uploadPicture(pic1Map, pic2Map); 
      call.enqueue...
  }
```

Some backends require the filename header parameter, that's why i use `@PartMap` this way. OkHttp's multipart builder does not set it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of RequestBody just use RequestBody. Fix method `uploadValues` in Retrofit interface:

```
           public interface RetrofitAdapter {
           @Multipart
           @POST("/TestApp/img_upload.php")
           Call<uploadResponseModel> uploadValues(@Part("value1")String  value1,@Part("value2")String  value2,@Part("fileToUpload1") TypedFile file1,@Part("fileToUpload2") TypedFile file2);
           }
```

And fix your request service:

```
           TypedFile file1 = new TypedFile("application/octet-stream", new File(path1));
           TypedFile file2 = new TypedFile("application/octet-stream", new File(path2));
           Call<uploadResponseModel> call = adapter.uploadValues("test1","test2",file1,file2);

           call.enqueue(new Callback<uploadResponseModel>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(Response<uploadResponseModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                   Log.i("TAG", "retro onResponse :" + response.body().getResponse().getStatus());

               }

               @Override
               public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                   Log.i("TAG", "retro onFailure :" + t.getCause());

               }
           });
```

Comment: yea i would have used your solution but `TypedFile` has been removed in `retrofit 2.0.0-beta2`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong `create` method of [`RequestBody`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/RequestBody.html).  You are passing a string, which uses the string as the content.  You need to be passing a `File`.  It is not clear what type your `path` variable is.  If it is already a `File`, use it.  Otherwise, create a file and pass that to `create` --

```
File image = new File(path.toString());
RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), image);
```

do the same for `fileBody1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method to sent normal string and file is different.

you should use

```
@Part("file\"; filename=\"fileToUpload1.png\"") RequestBody file1
```

instead of

```
@Part("fileToUpload1") RequestBody file1
```

or if you want to be specific

```
@Part("image\"; filename=\"fileToUpload1.png\"") RequestBody file1
```

Comment: does the filename need to have extension `.png`? coz that is just the php variable name i should be posting file with.

Comment: Hmmm I don't think so, why don't you try it first? :)

Answer (score -1):

There are some issues with multipart file upload with retrofit `@Multipart` tag.

Solved the issue using the `@POST` tag, with custom multipart builder in request body.

```
@POST ("userwebservices/app_upload_pic")
Call<APIRespone> uploadUserImages ( @Body RequestBody file );
```

Code for multipart upload by passing image file path getting from android app.

```
 File file = new File(filePath);

 MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = MediaType.parse("image/*");
 RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
         .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
         .addPart(
                 Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data;name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + filePath + "\""),
                 RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, file))
         .build();
```

Here `uploaded_file` is the checking string in the PHP script.